# SwiftUI TabView within ScrollView does not respect child's height

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, scrollview, tabview

I have a TabView within a ScrollView. Even though I give a fixed height to Color.orange of 500, the height of the TabView does not expand as it should.

The problem only appears when TabView is rendered within ScrollView.

```
struct TabViewProblems: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            TabView(selection: .constant(0), content:  {
                Color.orange.height(500)
            })
            .tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .always))
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

This problem does NOT exist when TabView or ScrollView are on there own.

```
struct TabViewProblems: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
//            TabView(selection: .constant(0), content:  {
                Color.orange.height(500)
//            })
//            .tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .always))
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct TabViewProblems: View {
    
    var body: some View {
//        ScrollView {
            TabView(selection: .constant(0), content:  {
                Color.orange.height(500)
            })
            .tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .always))
//        }
    }
}
```

[image]

How can this be fixed? I don't want to give TabView a fixed height, I want it to assume the height of it's contents.

The accepted answer for [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64136316/tabview-with-pagetabviewstyle-not-using-available-height-in-scrollview?rq=2) says that "when you set an infinite height on object inside the scrollview it takes only the space that the content really needs." Here, the content explicitly needs a height of 500, but that still is not being respected.

Comment: TabView should be the root view and is not intended to be inside other views.

Comment: With SwiftUI parents decide the size of the children. If you want the child to determine size you have to build that logic.

Answer (score 0):

I met the problem before, and I have a simple solution for it. You might use `ZStack` as below:

```swift
struct TabViewProblems: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            ZStack {
                Color.orange.height(500).hidden()
                TabView(selection: .constant(0), content: {
                    Color.orange.height(500)
                })
                .tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .always))
            }
        }
    }
}
```